# PHP Unable to connect to MS SQL server

Tags: php

I have used default MS SQL driver to connect to a SQL server in a php application.
I'm using XAMPP 1.6.8. my php version is 5.2.6.

Application was connected successfully to the SQL server and the application was running successfully for a long time. Now suddenly the application is showing an error on `mssql_connect()` function with same MS SQL access information.
the error is "Unable to connect to server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

I also checked the SQL server access info with a SQL client.  SQL client can connect successfully, therefore i think the access info is correct.

Can any one help me resolved this issue?

Thx

Comment: (1) Please proofread your post before clicking "submit". There are rules in English language about sentences. (2) Post your code.

Comment: What's the specific error message you're getting?

Comment: @Jon error is "Unable to connect to server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx."

Comment: I just found my solution here.
http://jimmyli.net/2009/03/php-unable-to-connect-to-mssql/

tha problem was that the file ntwdblib.dll packaged with PHP5 was an old version.
then i just replace with updated one from here http://jimmyli.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/ntwdblib.zip

Comment: @arif04cuet post an answer yourself to let future readers know

Comment: Then "suddenly" means "after upgrading PHP", doesn't it?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario no. suddenly means after 6-7 month later.no upgrading php.

Comment: @mnagel thanks for your reply.but unfortunately i can not submit answer.it's showing "an error occurred submitting answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my solution here. http://jimmyli.net/2009/03/php-unable-to-connect-to-mssql/ .problem was that the file ntwdblib.dll packaged with PHP5 was an old version. then i just replace with updated one from here http://jimmyli.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/ntwdblib.zip

Thx